# How to get nroff command to display font styles for man page

Tags: shell, command-line, syntax, macros, manpage

To test my man page, I'm using the nroff command.

```
$ nroff -man myfile
```

The results are formatted correctly, however my bold and italic font is not displayed.

Man page (myfile) source:

```
.TH Add 1 10/21/13
.SH NAME
add \- add metadata to items
.SH SYNOPSIS
.B add
.RB [ \-a | \-\-attribute
.IR key = value ]...
.RB [ \-t | \-\-tag
.IR tag ]...
.RB [ \-d | \-\-description 
.IR description ]
.RB [ \-n | \-\-note ]...
.IR item...
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bold text is indicated by `nroff` as repeated letters separated by a backspace. In other words, print the letter, back up, and print the letter again over top the first one, like an old typewriter. On the terminal , this is a no-op. `less` or some other pager will know to handle this specially, so try

```
nroff -man myfile | less
```

to see your bold text.